# Strip Punctuation From Text

Tags: python

I am writing a code for class that is supposed to use the Caesar cipher and I need to strip the punctuation from the text. However, whenever I enter a phrase with punctuation, it gives me a weird output, but not an error. The code works fine as long as I don't enter any punctuation.

```
#REQ denotes customer requirement
#importing string module for use later
import string
#defining the function encrypt
def encrypt(plaintext,shift):
    ans = ""
    #stripping the punctuation from the phrase
    new_ans = ans.translate(str.maketrans(' ', ' ', string.punctuation))
    for c in plaintext: #indexing each string character
        c = ord(c) + shift #using ord() to convert string to integar and then adding the user inputted shift
        if c > 122: #using if statement to make sure the shift starts back at "a" which is 97 on the ASCII Table
            c = c - 26
        c = chr(c) #converting the character back to a string      
        new_ans = new_ans + c #adding the shift to the character which now makes the Ceasar Cipher encoding complete
    return new_ans 

print('Lets encode a phrase using the Ceasar Cipher.')
shift1 = int(input('Enter the shift you want: '))#getting user shift and turning it into an integar
userinp2 = input('Please enter your phrase to be encoded: ')#getting user phrase to be coded
#printing the final output of the encoded phrase 
print(encrypt(userinp2,shift1))
```

OUTPUT

Please enter your phrase to be encoded: day#g&i
nki-q0s

I thought by using the string module, that would work.

Comment: You're stripping the punctuation from your empty result string, not from the plaintext.

Comment: Can you elaborate for me?

Answer (score 0):

To strip the punctuation from your text, you can do

```
if ord(c) > 65 and ord(c) < 122:
```

This range in the ascii table contains only alphabetical letters. So anything other than the alphabetical letters will be technically stripped from the text

Comment: where at in my code would I place this if statement

Answer (score 0):

Your issue happens right at the top of your function, when you strip the punctuation from your result string:

```
ans = ""
new_ans = ans.translate(str.maketrans(' ', ' ', string.punctuation))
```

That doesn't do anything useful, since the string `ans` was just initialized to be empty. It doesn't stay stripped if you later add non-letter characters to it. You probably want to be removing the punctuation from the input string, `plaintext`.

```
def encrypt(plaintext,shift):
    stripped_plaintext = plaintext.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))

    ans = ""
    for c in stripped_plaintext:
        ...
```

Note that I also replaced `' '` with `''` in the first two arguments to `maketrans`. Replacing each space with an identical space isn't really very useful. I suspect that was a typo, or perhaps a misreading of an example.

Note that this still won't fix all of your issues, as your logic for when to wrap around the alphabet is only valid for lowercase characters. If your input can contain capital letters, they might be shifted into punctuation characters that exist between the capitals and lowercase letters in ASCII. You might want to call `lower()` or `upper()` on the input string (before or after stripping the punctuation doesn't really matter). That way you only need to deal with a single case.

Comment: This worked. Thank you for explaining that. I am new to all of this and it was kicking my butt.